# Modulus and principal argument of $(−2+2i)^{(−3−4i)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have some problems trying to find the modulus and principal argument of $(−2+2i)^{(−3−4i)}$, I have worked with complex theory but in an abstract way and I have not done much with this type of accounts. Please, I would be grateful if you could help me in detail. Thanks in advance.

**My attempt was**

> $-2+2i=2{\sqrt 2}(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{i}{\sqrt 2})=2{\sqrt 2}e^{3\pi i/4}\rightarrow (-2+2i)^{(-3-4i)}=({2\sqrt 2}e^{3\pi i/4})^{(-3-4i)}=e^{3\pi}(2 \sqrt 2)^{(-3-4i)}e^{-9\pi i/4}$
> Then the following comes to mind:
> $(2 {\sqrt 2})^{(-3-4i)}=e^{(-3-4i)\ln 2{\sqrt 2}}=e^{-3\ln 2{\sqrt 2}}e^{-(4\ln 2{\sqrt 2})i}\Rightarrow |z|=e^{3\pi-3\ln 2{\sqrt 2}}\wedge \mathrm{Arg}(z)=-\frac{9\pi}{4}-4\ln 2{\sqrt 2} +(2\pi)(2)\approx 1.34 \in]-\pi,\pi[$

Comment: $|z| =\frac{e^{3 \pi}}{16 \sqrt{2}}$ and $\operatorname{Arg{z}}=1.3389$

Comment: @MrProof So where is my mistake? or maybe you have a more effective method.

Comment: You did not consider $i^2=-1$.

Comment: @MrProof Fixed typing error. So my procedure is correct?

Comment: I think it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $z^w:=e^{w\log z}=e^{w(\log|z|+i\arg(z))}$, therefore

$$
\arg(z^{w})=\operatorname{Re}(w)\arg(z)+\operatorname{Im}(w)\log |z|
$$

So the principal argument of $z^{w}$ is given for the unique value of $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

$$
(-3)\frac{3\pi}{4}+(-4)\log(2\sqrt{2})+2\pi k\in(-\pi,\pi]
$$

Using a CAS you can see that the principal value is attained when $k=2$, so $\arg(z^{w})\approx 1.3389$. About the modulus, we find that

$$
|z^w|=e^{-3\log(2\sqrt{2})+3\pi}\approx 547.639
$$